# reducing deployment jar size in Mule 4

Tags: mule-esb, mulesoft

Our organization is new to Mule 4. We are having some problems when deploying new api's. Some of our api's are taking around 10 minutes to deploy. We believe this delay is in part due to the much larger jars for Mule 4 api's compared Mule 3 deployments since all the dependent jars are packaged in the deployment jar. At times a new deployment will cause a crash and all the api's on the server will have to restart.

In Mule 3 I believe you could have multiple api's share common dependency's. This allowed us to have much smaller jars to deploy a new api. Is there any way other than domain projects to do this in Mule 4?

We have tried packaging lightweight jars using the command "mvn package -DlightweightPackage" but were unable to deploy these. Even if we place the needed repository structure in /lib/mule/repository , the lightweight packaged JAR no longer contain classloader-model.json to configure the application where to look for it's repository (dependencies) so they wouldn't properly deploy.

We have, however using a default package, removed resources (dependency tree) from the exploded JAR after server shutdown, moved the dependency tree to /lib/mule/resources (shared) and then we modified the "uri" in classloader-model.json within the exploded application (JAR). Then we started the server and the application works fine. This seemed to work but would force us to start and stop the server anytime we deployed something. We were hoping for a fix that would still allow us to do hot deployments.

Has anyone else run into this problem or have any thoughts on how to solve this problem other than increasing the resources on our server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can share dependencies by using a domain. Both connectors and libraries can be shared.

Note that using the method you described is undocumented and unsupported. It might disappear or change in a future release. I strongly recommend to avoid using it.

Lightweight packaged applications are not meant to be deployed, only to share projects.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a maven plugin which replaces all repository/**/*.jar files which are 
available in the local repo with a placeholder and later on copy back the files into
the mule-application.jar.

```
mvn io.github.c-a-services:mule4-jar-size-reducer-maven-plugin:LATEST:jar-compress
```

and later

```
mvn io.github.c-a-services:mule4-jar-size-reducer-maven-plugin:LATEST:jar-refill
```

For more options and automation see

[https://github.com/c-a-services/mule4-jar-size-reducer-maven-plugin](https://github.com/c-a-services/mule4-jar-size-reducer-maven-plugin#mule4-jar-size-reducer-maven-plugin)

The file itself then no longer needs so much space: ;-)

```
17:17:02 [INFO] refdata-2019.9.1-12-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.jar Size=81743321
17:17:02 [INFO] refdata-2019.9.1-12-SNAPSHOT-mule-application.zip Size=960544
```